# Создать матрицу с десятичными случайными числами

Tags: матрицы, c++

В `Eclipse` создать программу:

1. Создать массив из 10 целых случайных чисел, вывести на экран
2. Создать матрицу 5х8 с десятичными случайными числами, вывести на экран.

Помогите, пожалуйста!
Есть трудности в создании матрицы с десятичными случайными числами...какой тип надо присвоить что бы все выполнялось правильно?

Comment: >с десятичными случайными числами

Целые, вещественные?

>какой тип надо присвоить что бы все выполнялось правильно?

Что вы под этим подразумеваете?

Answer (score 2):

подключаем стандартную либу math

```
#include <math>
```

int array[5][8]; - обыкновенный статический массив

```
array[i][j] = rint(rand() * 100);
```